# Is there anything I could do to get Kiwi.com to give me a new route to not have a 13hr layover?

Tags: bookings, uk-citizens, connecting-flights, delays

My parents are abroad and they got an email that on their return flight the tickets have changed causing their layover to change from 2hrs to 13h 25m.

The ticket says "13h 25m layover protected by the Kiwi.com Guarantee" Does that mean I can ask for an alternative or something? (we have paid for the Guarantee)

They are flying back from Albania to UK. The connection flight is in Milan on the tenth of September.

How do I contact them?

Edit: I just found the help desk in kiwi.com under our account, is that where they'll get back to me?

Comment: You haven't said where your parents are flying from or to. It's possible that there is no alternative, or that possible alternatives are worse. You can always ask, but you might find your only 'alternative' is to cancel.

Comment: As far as I know, the “Kiwi guarantee“ just means that the two flights are on different bookings and that Kiwi will somehow vaguely try to make sure they get to their final destination in case a disruption in the first flight means they miss their second flight (this would be the airline’s responsibility if both flights where on a single booking). But you haven’t told us when they booked (I.e whether that was the layover they actually chose, or if the flights were changed and resulted in that long layover), what was the original layover, where from, where to...

Comment: @jcaron They are flying back from Albania to UK. Milan is the layover, as it originally was but now instead of 2 hours wait, it has changed to 13 hours (also added it in the body of the question)

Comment: Why did the layover change? Was a flight cancelled on the second leg?

Comment: It would be interesting to see if there is any EU261 compensation due for that change...

Comment: @DJClayworth no, they give no explanation. The flight is on the 10th of sept, I would have thought they'd have enough time to fix whatever the heck the problem is

Comment: Make sure your parents are able to enter Italy. You basically have two flights, and they will be entering the Schengen Area.

Comment: It is probably just as well. 13 hours is a safe margin for separate tickets; two hours isn't. You probably couldn't get through immigration, check in and then back through immigration in that time. On that note, you have to remember that because they are separate tickets, you may not be able to transit airside, and you may be denied boarding the first flight if you do not have the necessary travel documents to enter Italy.

Comment: @KristvanBesien British passport, they are returning home (to uk)

Comment: @MichaelHampton But that doesn't apply here, does it, they have British passports

Comment: @relidon In that case they can enter Italy no problem. But the rest of the comment still applies.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so there's no hope on them doing anything about it! They aren't even replying to the message I send them last night. Maybe they are right and this is wishful thinking in our part. Our thinking was because we paid for the guarantee they might give use a different date or something

Comment: They might not even be able to do anything. The airlines decide which flights will fly and what their schedules are. If they change, there is nothing that Kiwi can do but to book you on another flight.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do they have to clear immigration? Many international airports in the Schengen area have two zones, and you only need to go through immigration if arriving from a non-Schengen area, and either leaving the airport, or continuing on an intra-Schengen flight. Is Milan different -- I can't find out, but it does have a dedicated terminal for intra-Schengen flights (1A) and two for non-Schengen flights (1B and 1C).

Comment: What ended up happening in this situation, did they allow you to change this?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.